# How to add css class to <img> by TWIG to blog post?

Tags: css, laravel, twig, octobercms

How can I add CSS class to all pinned  in blog posts?
It would be great, if it possible make by TWIG. If it coulndt, can I add some php for this?

I just could come up with such a simple design.

```
<div class="markdown-body" itemprop="articleBody">
 {% for img in post.content_html %}
        {% set class = ['mbr-figure'] %} 
      {% endfor %}
 <p> {{ post.content_html | raw }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post how you want the final HTML to look?

Comment: Why do you need the classes on the img tag?

Comment: We are not clear what you exactly want in this .. post full code and your full requirements .. it wll help you and us.

Comment: 'mbr-figure' - is a class for img: responsive, border etc.

Comment: In final I want responsive img with border and center align.